# beautiful soup to csv

Tags: python, html, csv, beautifulsoup

There are a few threads on getting beautiful soup data to csv files but I can't find one that makes sense with my code.

I am scraping from WSJ biggest gainers. 3 to 103 gives me the top 100 stocks from the table in one day.

I am having a problem getting each value of a row on the table on a separate cell. There should be 6 cells per row with data. Then it should go to the next line and give me the next 6 data points (next stock).

Whenever I use the method below, it only outputs one row on the WSJ stock instead of looping many times and going to the next row each time. I'm not sure to make it so that the first 6 td tags are in row 1, then the next 6 td tags are in row 2.

I have tried making a list called cells with modifying symbol.text with no luck.

It would be even easier to make the first row all of the values in the first tr tag because there are six of them but they would need to be in their own cell. I have tried looping this with no luck also.

I am new to Python so the most simple code would be best.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

urlList = ['http://online.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3021-gainnyse-gainer.html',
       'http://online.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3021-gainnyse-gainer--20150806.html?mod=mdc_pastcalendar',
       'http://online.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3021-gainnyse-gainer--20150805.html?mod=mdc_pastcalendar',
       'http://online.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3021-gainnyse-gainer--20150804.html?mod=mdc_pastcalendar',
       'http://online.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3021-gainnyse-gainer--20150803.html?mod=mdc_pastcalendar']



for i in range(len(urlList)):
    url = urlList[i]            
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)         
    scrapeData = soup.select('tr')[3:103]    
    for symbol in scrapeData: 
       print(symbol.text)  



outputFile = open('wsjExample.csv', 'w')          
outputWriter = csv.writer(outputFile)
outputWriter.writerow(['Number', 'Symbol', 'Price', 'Change', '% Change', 'Volume'])
for row in range(len(scrapeData)):
    outputWriter.writerow([symbol('td')[0].text, symbol('td')[1].text, symbol('td')[2].text, symbol('td')[3].text, symbol('td')[4].text, symbol('td')[5].text])
outputFile.close()
```

Thanks,

Comment: Could you please provide a full minimum working example and fix your code formatting? You should at least provide the url with the desired data and fix your indentation. Where do you stumble exaclty? Could you extract the data from the webpage properly?

Comment: Okay I have fixed the formatting and added all of the code. I am able to extract the data no problem. When I run this program, it exports the same row over and over again instead of exporting the next row of data.

Comment: I just had a look at the html code of the webpage. Did you know that the whole table containing your data is in a div container of class `mdcTable`? So to get the table you could use `table = soup.find("table", { "class": "mdcTable" })`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are referencing `symbol('td')` outside of a loop that iterates over your data. What you are essentially doing is this:

```
scrapeData=[...] # list of the scraped data

for symbol in scrapeData:
    print symbol

# symbol is now set to the last item in scrapeData
# open file etc..
# for row in scrapeData length - do this next action that many times:
print symbol('td')[0] # this will print the first element in the symbol, which is the last element in scrapeData - there is no connection to the row at all.
```

What you need to do is scrape the values within your first loop over scrapeData - put it into a temporary list. Then iterate over the list when writing to the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

The table provided under the given URL can be accessed by `.find('table', {'class' : 'mdcTable'})` as I stated in my [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214563/beautiful-soup-to-csv?noredirect=1#comment52313834_32214563). The first row of the table needs to be ignored since this is the header and does not contain proper data (a little 'smart' implementation extracting the header as column names would be nice, but I haven't implemented something like this) which is done by `[1:]` in `for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]`.

To seperate data extraction and csv export I'm storing all extracted data into a dictionary `d` which is appended to a list called `data`. All the extracted values are formatted in a proper way to have integers, floats and strings as such as well as to remove unneeded new line characters or commas.

After all data is collected, stored in dicts and appended to the `data` list, the whole list is written to a csv file using [`DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) and the appropriate [`.writeheader()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter.writeheader) and [`.writerows()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) methods:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import csv
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3021-gainnyse-gainer.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', {'class' : 'mdcTable'})

data = []

for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    col = row.findAll('td')

    d = {    
            'rank' : col[0].getText(),
            'issue': col[1].getText(),
            'price' : col[2].getText(),
            'change' : col[3].getText(),
            'per_change' : col[4].getText(),
            'volume' : col[5].getText()
        }

    for key, val in d.items():
        val = val.replace('\n', '')
        val = val.replace(',', '')
        d[key] = val

        try:
            if key not in  ['rank', 'volume']:
                d[key] = float(val)
            else:
                d[key] = int(val)
        except Exception as e:
            pass

    data.append(d)

order = ['rank', 'issue', 'price', 'change', 'per_change', 'volume']

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=order)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to write in csv file :

```
import csv

with open('names.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

writer.writeheader()
writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'})
writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Lovely', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Wonderful', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
```