# How to extract news web scrapings into csv file and how to append new records?

Tags: python, web-scraping, export-to-csv

New to python and built a web scraper to pull down new news articles from cnn headlines. Trying to take the output which when I print() looks like a line by line item. Hoping to extract the results into a csv file so each headline is its own row. Also to then be able to write an append version so each time I run it, it appends to the file rather than overwrite it. The Question is how do I get the results to look like this in csv file:

1) Headline 1 from scraped data
2) Headline 2 from scraped data
3) Headline 3 from scraped data
 and so on.

I pasted my code below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
#nterwebsite you wish to pull from that has news articles
res = requests.get('http://money.cnn.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
#need to pul the ulcode from the website by right clicking and choosing inspecting element
news_box = soup.find('ul', {'class': '_6322dd28 ad271c3f'})
#drill down into the li's as they should always show a, which signals the header for the news article shown.
all_news = news_box.find_all('a')

for news in all_news:
  test=  (news.text)
  print(test)
with open('index.csv', 'w') as fobj:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(fobj, delimiter=',')
    for row in test:
        csvwriter.writerow(test)
```

Comment: Please ask a _clear_ question.

Comment: What the end csv file have to look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214563/beautiful-soup-to-csv

Comment: The end csv file should take each line from the scraped data and make it its own row in a csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re.compile` with `BeautifulSoup.find_all`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests, re
import csv
d = soup(requests.get('http://money.cnn.com/').text, 'html.parser')
articles = list(filter(None, [i.text for i in d.find_all('span', {'class':re.compile('^\w+ _\w+|^\w+$')})]))[2:]
with open('articles.csv', 'a') as f:
  write = csv.writer(f)
  write.writerows([[i] for i in articles])
```

Output:

```
What higher wages means for Domino's and McDonald's  
'Jurassic World' sequel has big opening day amid a surging box office 
Crying migrant girl: What the iconic photo says about press access 
Chanel reveals earnings for the first time in its 108-year history 
Why GE may need to stop paying its 119-year old dividend 
A top Netflix executive is out after using the N-word 
ZTE pays $1 billion fine to US over sanctions violations 
Tariffs on European cars would hurt US auto jobs 
Etsy sellers confront unknowns after Supreme Court ruling 
Chipotle hopes quesadillas and milkshakes bring customers back 
This group is getting ahead in America 
OPEC strikes deal to increase oil production 
Wall Street banks are healthier than ever 
Self-driving Uber driver may have been streaming 'The Voice' 
GM's new Chevy Blazer will be built in Mexico 
"GM is bringing back the Chevy Blazer, an SUV classic "
...
```